# How to list multiple lines in a table cell while using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm a new guy to Python(3.8.8).
I would like to create a file with tables by using python-docx(0.8.10).
At the time I'm trying to put a list with items into a certain cell of a table,
I found out that I can't switch a newline for every item, even when they're all end up with '\n'.

please refer to the code：

```
from docx import Document

list1 = ['this is the first line.\n', 'this is the second line.\n', 'this is the third line.\n']

doc1 = Document()
table1 = doc1.add_table(rows=3, cols=2, style = 'Table Grid')
table1.cell(2, 1).text = list1
doc1.save('C:\\temps\\doc1.docx')
```

My desired outcome is something like this：
[image]

However the outcome of my code is like this：
[image]

Can anyone give me some hints about how to solve this problem？
Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean "switch a newline"? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @scanny thanks for your question, I have added a picture of my current outcome after editing. "switch a new line" means I would like to let each sentence in a cell has its own line, without continuously connecting together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the text to a single str before assigning it to `cell.text`:

```
from docx import Document

list1 = ['this is the first line.\n', 'this is the second line.\n', 'this is the third line.\n']

doc1 = Document()
table1 = doc1.add_table(rows=3, cols=2, style = 'Table Grid')

# --- list of str is joined into single space-separated str ---
table1.cell(2, 1).text = " ".join(list1)

doc1.save('C:\\temps\\doc1.docx')
```